# Does the scattering wavefunction collapse "part-by-part"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, scattering, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-measurements

By "scattering wavefunction", I mean the wavefunction of the scattering product prior to measurement. This thing has a non-definite particle number, as well as a non-definite particle type.

My problem is that, we can't measure the entirety of the product **all at once**. More realistically, we detect some particles in the product before we detect others.

So, does the wavefunction "partly collapse" when we've only measured part of the product?

What is the precise formula for a partial collapse? I think we need to apply some notion of conditional probabilities here. For example, let's say the wavefunction of the product is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} |2\text{ positrons}, 1\text{ electron}\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} |3\text{ photons}, 1\text{ electron}\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} |1\text{ photon}, 1\text{ positron}\rangle$

Let's say we observe 1 electron first. This measurement should rule out the third term in the wavefunction, and cause a partial collapse to something like : $a |2\text{ positrons}, 1\text{ electron}\rangle+b |3\text{ photons}, 1\text{ electron}\rangle$

How exactly does the partial collapse work?

Comment: Yes, the intro textbook full collapse is just a special case which is actually quite rare in practice. The term for partial collapse that you're looking for is "POVM measurement" and should be covered in most quantum information books.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks. I will look up some books on that.  I checked the wikipedia, but there doesn't seem any formula to calculate the $a$ and $b$ in the second last paragraph of my post. Are the $a$ and $b$ unknown after the POVM measurement?